# Error in pattern matching in java

Tags: java, regex

I have one problem when i am using following code snippet

```
 String regexString=regexPair.get(paramName);

 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexString);
 Matcher m = p.matcher(paramMap.get(paramName)[0]);
 status = m.matches();
```

it return false

where  regexPair is hashmap and regexPair.get(paramName) is

```
"^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"
```

while I will ureplace

```
String regexString="^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"
```

then it works fine

`paramMap.get(paramName)[0]` return agsd@gmail.com.

I am not getting why this is occurring please help me.

Comment: regex is working fine there is some issue with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that `regexPair.get(paramName)` is the string you’ve given? Is that the result of some `println` call?

I suspect the quoting is not entirely the same. It may be that `regexPair.get(paramName)` actually contains `'\\'` followed by another `'\\'` (that is, two real backslashes in succession), while the replacement only contains `"\\"` (which is a single backslash). Note that the string `"(\\."` is really only 3 characters long.

Comment: Well, if `println` prints two backslashes, then there are two backslash characters in the string. You only want a single one, because two would only match a literal backslash. It seems the expression in `regexPair` is wrong.

Comment: thanks.you are right but when i am using it as string then why it is giving right result